# Get Specific Lists within a Collection of Lists?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-4.0

So, I have something like this, that gets a Huge List of information:

```
public List<Event> _EventList = Event.GetCachedList().OrderBy(u => u.GetUpcomingDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Date)).ToList();
```

I can now call upon some functions for outputting one of these at a time, like so

```
protected string GetEarliestDate()
{
    if(_EventList.Count > 0)
    {
        return "?date=" + _EventList.FirstOrDefault().DateList.FirstOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

protected string GetFormattedDate(List<DateTime> aDateList)
{
    if (aDateList.Count > 0)
    {
        return aDateList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.Date).ToString("MMMM dd");
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and there are more.  The Same variable `_EventList`

What I want to be able to do is to get separate `Lists` for each of these instead of calling upon the function for 1 of them.  For example, if the function can return all of these in a `List<String>` so that I can than use these String list returns to be converted into `JSON` Arrays.  I'm able to convert to json just fine, but trying to figure out how to turn them into separate lists of strings instead of just one string.

Also, How can I create a list from methods of the `_EventList` quickly, instead of doing this?

```
protected List<String> GetTitle(_EventList)
{
    List<String> theTitles = new List<String>();

    foreach(Event theEvent in _EventList)
    {
        theTitles.Add(theEvent.Title);
    }
    return theTitles;
}
```

So, this should return a List of all of the `Titles`.  There are just so many methods to gets lists of (from the returns of those methods).  Guess I'm just looking for an easier way to handle this.  Can anyone help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

are the Select() method what you need? The GetTitle() method can be the a single line code:

```
var theTitles = _EventList.Select(p => p.Title)
```

Select() helps you convert a list to another.

Comment: var dateStrings = _EventList.Select(p => return GetFormattedString(p));

Comment: `GetFormattedString` does not exist in the current context.  What is the namespace for this?

Comment: Also `theTitles` returns a list of `Events` instead of `Strings`, It needs to return a list of strings, but how?

Comment: var theTitles = _EventList.Select(p => p.Title) must get a list of strings if Title is of type String.  GetFormattedString  just an example ,you can replaced with you custom functions.Or you can do anything inside the {} like:   var date=_EventList.Select(p=> { if(true)return "somestring"; else return "another"});

Comment: Ok, yes, it does return a string.  Also, how to use the `GetFormattedDates`?  I have this, but get error:  `return aDateList.All(u => u.Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.Date()).ToString("MMMM dd");`

Comment: return aDateList.Select(u => u.Date.ToString("MMMM dd"));  You can only use "=>" once in a single call.